# Integration media foundation transform with zxing library

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-8.1, zxing, ms-media-foundation

We have made an bar code and QR code scanner app for windows surface tablets 8.1. We have used ZXing library and implemented by keeping "Scan Code" button on UI.

But we want auto recognition feature without using button click. We have heard about Media Foundation transform (MFT) in .net whoch can be used to process each video frame. If  we start recording video using media capture element once application launches, then MFT can be used to process each video frame automatically.

But we are not getting how to integrate MFT with ZXing library?If at all there is any paid library, let me know.

Comment: Integration is possible. Can you provide more information about this "media capture element" that you are planning to use?

Comment: Unless you are looking at an interop wrapper, MFT is native.  However Media Foundation is a pleasure to use and performs great.  As a result, I suggest you use Media Foundation to capture as well.   With respect to capture, a library would only duplicate most of what you have already have, since an MFT is nearly always used with a source (in the topology somewhere).

Comment: @Jeff : We have used media capture element to capture barcode or QR code image. The we pass on this image to Zxing library which decodes it. If you can provide some link for interop wrapper, it will be appriciable.

Comment: @Vaibhav: Understood.  You are already using a wrapper, and I am not sure that an MFT fits your situation like you are hoping.  And I don't think you would want to send every frame to Zxing.  Three per second should be sufficient (perhaps a timer).  Otherwise, you are needlessly pounding the CPU.  And that would very simple.

Answer (score -1):

You can get autorecognition and detect any barcode/QR code in your app with this:
https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect#realtime-video-analysis-and-qr-code-detection (For decoding it uses ZXing)

Tried out and works. Just install the nuget package, and read the sample app: 
https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect/tree/master/VideoEffects/QrCodeDetector